# How to formally represent a function whose elements are sets?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let us suppose that I have two sets: A and B.

$A = \{0,2,4,6,8\}$
$B = \{1,3,5,7,9\}$

Let us suppose that I have a function f that maps elements of A and elements of B to the natural numbers ($\mathbb{N}$). I think that I can formalize this function in this way:

$f: A \times B \to \mathbb{N}$

However, how can I formalize a function t that maps subsets of A and subsets of B to subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?

I think that I can do this, by replacing the sets A, B, and $\mathbb{N}$, of the formal definition of f, by their respective power sets, in this way:

$t: \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, correct!..

Comment: This is totally fine.

Comment: Strictly speaking, shouldn't it be $f : A \sqcup B \to \mathbb{N}$ and $t : \mathcal P(A) \sqcup \mathcal P(B) \to \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, where $\sqcup$ denotes the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union)? (Or, since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint to begin with, you may think of $\sqcup$ as being simply the union.) From your description, it is not clear that you want $f$ to map ordered pairs $(a,b)$ to the natural numbers...